# The bottom scroll button on the fixed left menu is not visible in some cases

Tags: html, css

I try to implement the page layout with the fixed header, footer, left menu (can be scrollable) and the content section that can be scrollable by the browser scroll. The layout is almost done, but I've realized that there is a problem with the left menu scroll panel. When I'm changing browser size to smaller one, the bottom scroll button is not visible as presented on the picture.

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how can I fix it?

jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/76UZm/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="top-bar">
    <div id="topbar-inner">Top bar text</div>
</div>
<div id="left">
    <div id="left-header">
            <h3>Nice header</h3>

    </div>
    <div id="left-inside">
        <ul>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
            <li>menu item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mainouter">
    <p>Content start</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content end</p>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="bottom-inner">Fixed Bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 23px;
}
#topbar-inner {
    height: 23px;
    background: #bbb;
}
#mainouter {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    background: #ccc;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
#bottom-inner {
    height: 40px;
    background: #aaa;
}
#left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 149px;
}
#left-header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    height: 20px;
}
#left-inside {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 120px;
    height: 95%;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the height percentage of `#left-inside`. Your `#bottom` division of `20px` is overlapping the `#left-inside`, `height:95%;` must compensate with your window height.
 Try the following code then you will surely understand the situation:

`#left-inside {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 120px;
    height: 90%;   //before 'height:95%;' I just changed this. Now you can see the bottom  scroll button poking there...
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
  }`

Comment: But when I reduce the height, then the div ends before the footer div and there is an empty space between..

Comment: this is because the division is fixed so it is independent of everything else...
now try this one ...

    `#left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 149px;
    overflow: auto;
     }
    #left-inside {
    /*overflow: auto;*/
   
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
    }`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've changed your solution and created something that is fine for me :) http://jsfiddle.net/76UZm/5/

Answer (score 1):

That's because your list elements are breaking into two lines and the second line of the last list item pushes it down.
The solution is simple, add below to your css:

```
#left-inside >ul > li {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

> [**UPDATED DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/76UZm/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your solution has resolved the problem but only partially. When you will reduce the browser window size more then you can see that the problem still exists. IMO the problem is related to the #left-header div. Without this div it works great, when I set overflow on #left div.

Comment: @woytech I've re-sized it to as small as possible and it still works for me, on Chrome. And I believe most user will not reduce the height to that extent :)